# Junit test case for PreparedStatementCallback coverage

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

```
@Transactional
    public Boolean save(final StudentLogEntry studentLogEntry) throws SQLException,DaoException{
        boolean returnFlag = true;
        String sqlInsert = "insert into STUDENT_DETAILS (INSERT_DATE,STUDENT_NAME,STUDENT_ID) values(SYSDATE,?,?)";
        returnFlag = jdbcTemplate.execute(
            sqlInsert,
            new PreparedStatementCallback<Boolean>() {
                Boolean b=false;
                @Override
                public Boolean doInPreparedStatement(PreparedStatement pst) {
                    try {
                        pst.setString(2, studentLogEntry.getStuName());
                        pst.setString(3, studentLogEntry.getStuId());
                        b=pst.execute();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        clicklogger.info("SQLException has occurred while inserting studentlog ",e);
                    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
                        clicklogger.info("DataAccessException has occurred while inserting studentlog ",e);
                    }
                    return b;
                }
            }
        );
        return returnFlag;
    }
```

I am using Spring framework for my project, I have written Junit test case for the above code. But I am not able to cover the `PreparedStatementCallback`. My test case is as below:

```
@Test
public void testSave() throws DaoException, SQLException {
    studentDao.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
    studentDao.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    StudentLogEntry studentLogEntry = new StudentLogEntry();
    studentLogEntry.getStuName("ABC");
    studentLogEntry.getStuId("1234");
    assertEquals("true",studentDao.save(studentLogEntry));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug the `save` method while running the test? Especially the call `jdbcTemplate.execute(...)`.

Comment: Yes I have debugged the save method while testing, Control fails when it enters inside doInPreparedStatement.

Answer (score 0):

The method is doing to much to make it easily and clearly testable.

**1)** I would move the new `PreparedStatementCallback` to a specialized class:

```
public class MyPreparedStatementCallback implements PreparedStatementCallback<Boolean>{

  @Override
  public Boolean doInPreparedStatement(PreparedStatement pst) {
    ....
}
```

I would test the `doInPreparedStatement` method in separation here. It should not be related to the former test at all.

**2)** Use the new class in the original method and test whether proper instance has been passed (you would need Mockito [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all/1.9.5)):

```
returnFlag = jdbcTemplate.execute(sqlInsert,new MyPreparedStatementCallback());
```

and the test:

```
@InjectMocks
StudentDao studentDao;

@Mock
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateMock;

@Captor
ArgumentCaptor argCaptor;

@Before
public void init(){
     MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void shouldSaveWithCallback(){   
     // Act
     // set up
     studentDao.save(studentLogEntry);
     myClass.userPressedButton();

    Mockito.verify(jdbcTemplateMock).execute(Mockito.anyString(), argCaptor.capture());

    // Assert
    assertTrue(argCaptor.getValue() instance of MyPreparedStatementCallback);
}
```

The **bottom line** is that you should not test the implementation of that callback withing your original test method. That is too much and your test would be to coarse and hard to maintain.